# css transparent body excluding images

Tags: css, transparency, opacity

I have this code

```
    body {
        background-color: #808080;
        background-image: url('/Content/img/emboss.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center 250px;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10pt;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
    img {
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

However it doesn't work. The entire site, every element has an opacity of 0.8 which is what I want and it looks perfect. However when rendering an image I don't want any transparency.

How would I go about doing this in my css

Comment: I don't think you can override parent opacity from a child:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886830/how-to-override-opacity-for-a-child

Comment: Elements in body can have max opacity as its parent, `.8`. Set `opacity: .8` to elements which don't contain `img`, not `body`.

Comment: Use `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);` in body if you don't mind

Comment: override opacity for img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use opacity property for this kind of effect. Rather create a div over the body and keep its background color as rgba (255,255,255,0.8) and then add image inside that div.

Changing alpha values is the only way of separating the opacity of a parent to its child.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using little trick. Use `:not` pseudo selector like below.

```
 body {
    background-color:#808080;
    background-image: url('/Content/img/emboss.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 250px;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
   }
   body :not(img)
   {
    opacity:0.7;
   }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/4ycfujs7/)

Comment: it will work. did you apply the same code what i have written?

Comment: Yes, copy and paste. Images are still transparent, however I see it works in your DEMO