# Opacity background but no opacity text

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I have a div with a gray background with opacity.

```
        <div className="absolute w-full h-full top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 bg-slate-500 opacity-50 z-10">
          <p className="relative top-1/2 px-8 text-center heading-3 text-black">
            Here is some text.
          </p>
        </div>
```

However, the opacity overlays the text as well. It makes my text color not be black, instead black with opacity. How do I remove the opacity for the p tag?

Comment: add full opacity on p's classes.

Comment: The top result when searching for "tailwind background opacity": https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-opacity

Comment: @billybadass That's not how opacity works, see: [How to override opacity for a child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21886830/how-to-override-opacity-for-a-child)

Comment: Sorry guys it's `bg-opacity-50` not `opacity-50`.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the element a background-color with an rgba value, e.g.:

`background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);`

The background-color will have the opacity, but not the rest of the element and it's children.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.php

I don't know Tailwind, but it looks like you can achieve it with the following pattern: `bg-sky-500/75`, whereas 75 is the opacity.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity